# Passing address of a public variable in a function using pointers

Tags: c#

So I have a method that takes each single word from a TextBox and passes it to the registry function below. The main idea is that if it finds any of the case words it should give me the equivalent address of public variable that I can later operate on, but in the "int* pointer = &AH" part I get following error:

error CS0212: You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer

which means that I can't get address of a public variable.
I know it is not the greatest way to do this but that is what I had on mind.

```
public byte AH = 0, AL = 0, BH = 0, BL = 0, CH = 0, CL = 0, DH = 0, DL = 0;

        unsafe public int registry(string register)
        {
            switch (register)
            {
                case "AH":
                    int* pointer = &AH;
                    return *pointer;
                case "AL":
                    return AL;
                case "BH":
                    return BH;
                case "BL":
                    return BL;
                case "CH":
                    return CH;
                case "CL":
                    return CL;
                case "DH":
                    return DH;
                case "DL":
                    return DL;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Pointers are not integers in C#. Aside from `unsafe` you also need `fixed`, but then you cannot return the resulting pointer, and even if you could, it would not remain valid. Depending on what exactly you're going for you could make the method return a `ref byte` (and then do `return ref AH`); then you don't need `unsafe` either.

Comment: This is **not** a compelling scenario for the use of pointers. If this is "what you had in mind" then you are experiencing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What would you hope to *do* with this pointer? About the only thing you can do without breaking things is print the value of the pointer. If you want to modify the value through the pointer, then using a `ref` achieves so safely, without managing pointers. This will not work if these are local variables, but then of course neither will returning a pointer, since it will become invalid the moment the method ends. C# is not C; it has garbage collection and as part of that it reserves the right to move objects around whenever it wants, which is why playing around with pointers rarely makes sense.

Comment: Ok thanks for help, I will try to do it as you said.

Comment: If you're trying to model the register file of an x86 processor, then probably better than any of this indirect stuff is modeling it as `Dictionary<string, byte>` (e.g. `registers[register] = 42`). You can do a one-time initialization with `Dictionary<string, byte> registers = new() { { "AH", 0 }, { "AL", 0 }, ... }`.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I did that and it works good, but now I have a problem, for example two 8 bit registers AH and AL should be part of one 16 bit register AX (the lower and higher byte) and I don't know how to corelate them.

Comment: First, abstract the register access behind a method or indexer (`this[string]`). Then you can customize the behavior based on the argument. I recommend switching to the full 16-bit registers and storing those (`ushort ax, bx, cx, dx`) and implementing access to the 8-bit registers as bit mask operations (`al = ax & 0xff`, `ah = ax >> 8` for getting, `ax = (ax & 0xff00) | al`, `ax = (ax & 0x00ff) | (ah << 8)` for setting, season with casts as necessary).

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I understand the bit mask part but I have problem with indexer. I have read documentation about "this" keyword and tried to somehow use it but I think that I don't really understand it. Could you help me a little with this one?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lfdDhG). Admittedly this does get a little repetitive with writing out all the registers, so if you want even larger register files (like for 32- or even 64-bit processors) more sophisticated code that parses the register names is probably in order. But for a simple simulation this is hard to beat in clarity.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot :)